# SBCL error with cl-smtp

Tags: email, smtp, common-lisp, postfix-mta, sbcl

This is a recent error that I can't find any documentation for. It might not be `cl-smtp` specific, but it occurs each time I attempt to evaluate

```
 (cl-smtp:send-email "localhost" "source@email.com" "test@email.com" "TEST" "Testing email from Common Lisp")
```

from the REPL. The error output is

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR in thread #<THREAD
                                                              "initial thread" RUNNING
                                                              {AAE38D1}>:
  invalid keyword argument: :SERVE-EVENTS (valid keys are :AUTO-CLOSE, :INPUT,
  :OUTPUT, :ELEMENT-TYPE, :EXTERNAL-FORMAT, :BUFFERING, :TIMEOUT).

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-PCL::CHECK-APPLICABLE-KEYWORDS
 0
 (:AUTO-CLOSE :INPUT :OUTPUT :ELEMENT-TYPE :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :BUFFERING
  :TIMEOUT)
 -303677905
 10)
0] 0
```

I'm running Debian 6 with postfix and SBCL 1.0.40, and `cl-smtp` installed via `quicklisp`. Sending email through the `telnet` interface with the same source, server, target, subject and body (whether from the same unix user or with root) works fine. This setup also works fine (even from the REPL) on other machines that run the same software stack.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, that flag isn't in cl-smtp. I suspect it's an error in the threading lib that cl-smtp is using. Have you tried updating to SBCL 51?

Comment: @Paul Nathan - Switching up to 51 and re-installing the appropriate libaries seemed to work (though what the error was is still a mystery). Wanna toss that up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular error is not coming from cl-smtp. Miscellany googling suggests that it's an internal API mimatch.  Looking at the available flags, it seems as if it's a socket error( input, output, buffering, timeout).

SBCL 40 is almost a year old, SBCL 51 is fresh off the presses... I suggest upgrading!